# Is there an element of order $n$ in all roots of $x^n - 1$ modulo $q$ where $q$ is a prime number and $n \mid q-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

In the field of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ where $q$ is a prime, if $n \mid q-1$, then

$$
x^n - 1 = (x - \omega_1) (x - \omega_2) \cdots (x - \omega_n)
$$

where $\omega_i$ is a root of $x^n-1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. I want to prove that at least one of all the $\omega_i$ has order $n$; that is, there exists some $\omega_i$ such that
$$
\omega_i^n = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \omega_i^k \neq 1 \;\; \forall 1\leq k < n
$$

I think it's true; moreover, I guess there are $\phi(n)$ such elements of order $n$ since there are when considering the $n$ roots of $x^n-1$ in complex field $\mathbb{C}$. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a property of cycllic groups, and arguments with varying assumptions on the background can be given (can do without assuming cyclicity). The theme has been discussed thoroughly in older threads, but I don't have the time to look for the best duplicate target. You are all relative newbies, so +1 and smiles to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \mathbb{Z}^*= \mathbb{Z_q} -\{0\}$ is always a cyclic group under multiplication. It has $q-1$ elements. We know that, if G is a finite cyclic group of $m$ elements and if $n|m$, then there exists a unique cyclic subgroup of order $n$. This subgroup, being cyclic, must have $\varphi(n)$ generators. And you have pointed it out right, that in the given case, there are $\varphi(n)$ elements with order $n$.

Comment: What if we do not consider field $\mathbb{Z}_q$ but arbitrary field? I mean, if we only know that $x^n - 1$ splits in some field, must there exists an element of order $n$?

Comment: Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field of characteristic $p$ (which may even be 0). Suppose the polynomial $x^n-1$ splits in some extension $L$ of $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose $n$ is not divisible by $p$ (if $p$ is non zero), then $x^n-1$ has got distinct roots in $L$. Now, the roots of $x^n-1$ forms a group of order $n$ under multiplication of $L$. Clearly, any finite subgroup of a multiplicative group of any field is cyclic. Hence the group of roots of $x^n-1$ must be cyclic. In such a situation, there exists an element of order $n$ under multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you assume that $n \mid q-1$, then $q \nmid n$. Notice that, if $q \mid n$ (thus $n=kq$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), then $(x^n-1) = (x^k-1)^q$, therefore a root of unity can't have order $n$ (unless $n=q$).

You can define the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(x) := \prod_{k \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*} (x-\zeta^k) \in \mathbb{Z}_q[x]$ where $\zeta \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}_q}$ (algebraic closure) is a (not necessarily primitive, we will prove it is primitive) $n$-th root of unity. You can then factor by the divisors of $n$ the polynomial $x^n-1 \in \mathbb{Z}_q[x]$ as:
\begin{align*}
x^n-1 = \prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x).
\end{align*}
In other words, I have rephrased your question by looking specifically at a zero of $\Phi_n$, which is a root of unity. Now you wish to prove that $\zeta$ has order $n$. Assume that $\zeta$ doesn't have order $n$, let's say the order of $\zeta$ is $m$. Because we know that $\zeta^n=1$, we know that $m|n$. Then, let's look at:
\begin{align*}
\prod_{l|m}\Phi_l(x) = x^m-1.
\end{align*}
Now, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x) = (x^m-1) \cdot \prod_{d|n, d \nmid m }\Phi_d(x) = x^n-1.
\end{align*}
We know that $n \nmid m$. The contradiction now follows if you assume that $q \nmid n$, which I will leave for you to find out (use separability of $x^n-1 \in \mathbb{Z}_q[x]$).